# Regex split quoted string and preserve the quotes

Tags: regex

I have to split a quoted string by space preserving the spaces and special charaters.

This string `"quoted string, with comma, and quote."`
to be:

```
'"quoted '
'string, '
'with '
'comma, '
'and '
'quote."'
```

I have this regex `/\b(?![\s.,])/`, but this splits the first `"` into a separate word, like this:

```
'"'
'quoted '
...
```

How to make this quote go onto first word?

Comment: Which language are you using? In case there are differences in regex implementation?

Comment: javascript split function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using the following *regex* :

```
"?[\w,."]+\s?
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mVXGls/1)**

**JavaScript**

```js
var str = '"quoted string, with comma, and quote."';
var result = str.match(/"?[\w,."]+\s?/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If there might be multiple spaces that you want to keep, this will not get them - a slight modification to @siam expression: `"?[\w,."]+\s*` looks like it would do it?  Not sure if you have this situation